# Use array and return values one by one

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to run the code which has assigned some arrays in 2 worksheets and based on match returns the data from one sheet to the other.

**In the sheet1:**

Here, I have 3 columns of data (for an example there is not so many rows, but it will be many more):
[image]

**In the sheet 2 I have the following data:**
[image]

Therefore, what I want to do is to match the column C in sheet2 with column A in sheet 1, i.e. match based on the IDs. Based on this match, and If in sheet2 in column E is the text 'Yes', then from sheet1 column A and column B, I want to write the values into the sheet2, respectively in columns F and G. I.e. 'Name' and 'Number'.

Therefore this is my desired outcome to achieve in sheet2 after running the code:
[image]

I wanted to assign the columns of data from sheet1 to arrays and the same for column with IDs in sheet2. I will have much more data!

The problem with my code is that instead of returing the values from sheet1 one after another based on match with iID in sheet2, it actually returns only the first values for 'Name' and 'Number' from sheet1 for as many 'Yes' as it is in sheet2 (It doubles the returned values) instead of returning one after the other.

This is my code:

```
Sub test()

Dim w_result As Worksheet
Dim w1 As Worksheet

Dim r As Long
Dim d As Long
Dim intLastRow As Long
Dim IntLastRow_Result As Long
Dim IntLastCol As Long

Dim arrID() As Variant
Dim arrName() As Variant
Dim arrNumber() As Variant


With ThisWorkbook
    Set w1 = .Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set w_result= .Sheets("Sheet2")
End With


With w1
    intLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    IntLastRow_Result = w_result.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row

    arrID = .Range(.Cells(5, 3), .Cells(intLastRow, 3))
    arrName= .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(intLastRow, 1))
    arrNumber= .Range(.Cells(5, 2), .Cells(intLastRow, 2))


   For r = 1 To UBound(arrID , 1)
        If Len(arrID (r, 1)) > 0 Then
            For d = 4 To IntLastRow_Result
                If w_result.Cells(d, 3) = arrID (r, 1) Then
                    If w_result.Cells(d, 5) = "Yes" Then
                        w_result.Cells(d, 6) = arrName(r, 1)
                        w_result.Cells(d, 7) = arrNumber(r, 1)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next r

End With

End Sub
```

I will be very much appreciated for any help on that!

Comment: what is the value of intLastRow1 i think it is intLastRow

Comment: For the sake of asking... why are you working through these arrays?  It *looks* like you're just trying to sort the data from table 1, which doesn't require VBA, plus adding a **label** column which is not part of the original sheet (so not sure how that is being accounted).  have you attempted to just sort the data, even if you need to copy the original data to another sheet as to not disturb the source data?

Comment: The label 'Yes' signifies how many names with the number should be actually transferred to sheet2, e.g. I have 'Yes' in 2 rows with matching ID to sheet1, this means that only two first names and numbers should be transferred. I cannot sort the data because I have completely different layout in sheet2 than in sheet1. On the top of that, the data from sheet1 is only a small sample for sake of example. Normally I will have much more data there

Comment: I need to use arrays because I will have a lot of 'Names' and 'number' rows in the sheet1 assigned to different IDs, i.e. id1, id2, id3. In the example, I have narrowed it to records until id2.

Comment: @techie : the intLasRow1 was supposed to be IntLastRow_Result. I have corrected it in the post.

Comment: This looks like a job for a database. You can use PowerQuery in Excel to work with Excel tables as if they were a database. Or you could look in to Access. You'll get much better performance in Access with large datasets. Plus, you can solve problems like this with saved queries.

Comment: @Dozens, I think you can try to use autofilter, I hope it will be more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that each time a match is found, the `For d =`... loop overwrites previous results.

A quick and dirty fix is to test the result row for empty, if found to be empty write result, then exit the inner for loop.

```
Sub test()
    Dim w_result As Worksheet
    Dim w1 As Worksheet

    Dim r As Long
    Dim d As Long
    Dim intLastRow As Long
    Dim IntLastRow_Result As Long
    Dim IntLastCol As Long

    Dim arrID() As Variant
    Dim arrName() As Variant
    Dim arrNumber() As Variant

    Dim ResultRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set w1 = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set w_result = .Sheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    With w1
        intLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        IntLastRow_Result = w_result.Cells(w_result.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row '<~~ removed implicit active sheet reference

        arrID = .Range(.Cells(5, 3), .Cells(intLastRow, 3))
        arrName = .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(intLastRow, 1))
        arrNumber = .Range(.Cells(5, 2), .Cells(intLastRow, 2))

        For r = 1 To UBound(arrID, 1)
            If Len(arrID(r, 1)) > 0 Then
                For d = 4 To IntLastRow_Result
                    If w_result.Cells(d, 3) = arrID(r, 1) Then
                        If w_result.Cells(d, 5) = "Yes" Then
                            If IsEmpty(w_result.Cells(d, 6)) Then '<~~~ Added
                                w_result.Cells(d, 6) = arrName(r, 1)
                                w_result.Cells(d, 7) = arrNumber(r, 1)
                                Exit For  '<~~~ Added
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

<sub>Note: this is a very inefficient solution, but will do ok for small data sets.</sub>

---

Here's a more efficient version, utilising a Variant Array for the results, and updating the start index of the inner loop

```
Sub test()
    Dim w_result As Worksheet
    Dim w1 As Worksheet

    Dim r As Long
    Dim d As Long
    Dim intLastRow As Long
    Dim IntLastRow_Result As Long
    Dim IntLastCol As Long

    Dim arrID() As Variant
    Dim arrName() As Variant
    Dim arrNumber() As Variant
    Dim Results() As Variant
    Dim ResultStart As Long
    Dim ResultRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set w1 = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set w_result = .Sheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    With w1
        intLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        IntLastRow_Result = w_result.Cells(w_result.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row '<~~ removed implicit active sheet reference
        Results = w_result.Cells(1, 1).Resize(IntLastRow_Result, 8).Value
        w_result.Activate
        arrID = .Range(.Cells(5, 3), .Cells(intLastRow, 3))
        arrName = .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(intLastRow, 1))
        arrNumber = .Range(.Cells(5, 2), .Cells(intLastRow, 2))

        ResultStart = 4
        For r = 1 To UBound(arrID, 1)
            If Len(arrID(r, 1)) > 0 Then
                For d = ResultStart To IntLastRow_Result
                    If Results(d, 3) = arrID(r, 1) Then
                        If Results(d, 5) = "Yes" Then
                            If IsEmpty(Results(d, 6)) Then '<~~~ Added
                                Results(d, 6) = arrName(r, 1)
                                Results(d, 7) = arrNumber(r, 1)
                                Exit For  '<~~~ Added
                            End If
                        End If
                        ResultStart = ResultStart + 1
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next r
    End With
    w_result.Cells(1, 1).Resize(IntLastRow_Result, 8).Value = Results
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Why would it be inefficient for a bigger dataset? Would the solution proposed by Dean (above) work for a bigger datasets?

Comment: Similar to Dean's. Moving the result data to an array is the key (just like you do for the source data).  Place it on the sheet in one go at the end.  Also track the last row checked in the result range and start the inner For loop from there.

Comment: Please try use autofilter as another alternative

Answer (score 1):

The way I would solve approach this is the following. First, if you are working with a large dataset in Excel you do not want to loop through the front end range, but rather, loop through arrays (memory).

Now, how do we use arrays effectively? Well, what do we need? We need an array for the Sheet1 data, we need and array for the Sheet2 output data. Store your sheet1 data to an array AND store your sheet2 “template” data to an array for mapping purposes.

Sample data:

[image]

[image]

See below code. You will note that this approach will speed up your process time massively!

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TransferUsingArrays()

    Dim wsS1 As Worksheet, wsS2 As Worksheet
    Dim aSheet1() As Variant, aSheet2() As Variant
    Dim lRowS1 As Long, lRowS2 As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long


    'set the worksheets - use workbook qualifier!
    Set wsS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsS2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")


    lRowS1 = wsS1.Range("A" & wsS1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lRowS2 = wsS2.Range("C" & wsS2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    'set the arrays
    aSheet1 = wsS1.Range("A4").Resize(lRowS1, 3)
    aSheet2 = wsS2.Range("C3").Resize(lRowS2, 5)


    'now loop through the data array and match with sheet2 array entry
    For i = 2 To lRowS1
        'if there is a name, only look for match
        If Len(aSheet1(i, 1)) > 0 Then
            'now loop through second array to insert latest value
            For j = 2 To lRowS2
                'if the id is a match
                If aSheet2(j, 1) = aSheet1(i, 3) Then
                    'if there is a blank in name and there is yes in value
                    If aSheet2(j, 5) = "" And aSheet2(j, 3) = "Yes" Then
                        'now insert the values into second array
                        aSheet2(j, 4) = aSheet1(i, 2)
                        aSheet2(j, 5) = aSheet1(i, 1)
                        'now exit
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

    'now output the second array
    wsS2.Range("C3").Resize(lRowS2, 5) = aSheet2


End Sub
```

Desired result:

[image]

Naturally adjust the code where needed.

I hope this is what you are looking for..,

Answer (score -1):

This example with assumption the content sheet2 and sheet1 as like as s/o sample, and sheet1 content is sorted by id:

```
Sub test()

    Dim w_result As Worksheet
    Dim w1 As Worksheet

    Dim r As Long
    Dim d As Long
    Dim intLastRow As Long
    Dim IntLastRow_Result As Long
    Dim IntLastCol As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set w1 = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set w_result = .Sheets("Sheet2")
    End With


    With w1
        intLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        IntLastRow_Result = w_result.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

        arrNumber = .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(intLastRow, 3))

        Dim LastID As String
        LastID = ""
        lastrow = 0

        For r = 1 To UBound(arrNumber, 1)

            If Len(arrNumber(r, 3)) > 0 Then
                If arrNumber(r, 3) <> LastID Then
                   LastID = arrNumber(r, 3)
                   If arrNumber(r, 3) = "id1" Then lastrow = 4
                   If arrNumber(r, 3) = "id2" Then lastrow = 29
                   Else
                       lastrow = lastrow + 1
                End If

                If w_result.Range("E" & lastrow) = "Yes" Then
                   w_result.Range("F" & lastrow) = arrNumber(r, 1)
                   w_result.Range("G" & lastrow) = arrNumber(r, 2)
                End If

            End If
         Next r

    End With


End Sub
```